# GPS Module Losing Fix

Tags: gps

I have a remote RPI that I need to have accurate time. I have a GPS module, interfacing through USB. The module functions normally by itself, I can see the 1 Hz led after ~10s.

I am calling this script in crontab periodically:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e "/dev/ttyACM0" ]
then
exit
else
GPSDATE=""

until [ "$GPSDATE" != "" ]; do
GPSDATE=`gpspipe -n 10 -w | grep TPV | grep -e '"mode":[23]' | grep '"time":' | sed -r 's/.*"time":"([^"]*)".*/\1/' | tail -1`
done

date --utc -s "$GPSDATE"
fi
```

Experimenting with this script I see the system time updated to the GPS time. The problem is that a minute or so after boot the GPS will no longer get a fix. I ran the GPS all night plugging into a usb charger (No RPI) and it kept a constant fix.

Is there something I am missing that could kill the ability of the GPS to get a fix?

It is this GPS:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B084MK8BS2?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084MK8BS2)

Thanks
Rich

Comment: have you checked the gpsd daemon?